# Is there a difference between a "brushless motor" and a "motor without brushes"?

Tags: motors

On the Dyson website they promote their new motor by saying:

> Dyson Hyperdymium™ motors work very differently to conventional
> brushed motors. We replaced the brush with digital pulse technology,
> added neodymium magnets and built a ceramic shaft that's three times
> stronger than steel. This makes our motors durable and powerful, yet
> smaller, lighter and cleaner than ever before.

I find it odd that they are referring to their motor as a brushed motor, having replaced the brushes - as opposed to simply calling it a brushless motor.

To my knowledge, the main difference between brushed and brushless motors is that on a brushed motor the coils are on the rotor and the magnet on the stator, and with a brushless motor, this is the other way around.

I am having trouble finding any in-depth information about Dyson's motor, but from these two images on their website:

[image]
[image]

it looks like the coils could be on the rotor - which would explain why they are referring to it as a brushed motor, but without brushes.

Is this the case? Is there a semantic difference between a "brushless motor" and a "motor without brushes", or are Dyson trying to be sneaky and imply that they invented the brushless motor...?

Comment: They don't say it is a brushed motor. They say it works differently to one.

Comment: Yeah, i know they don't **say** its a brushed motor - my question is why are they mentioning brushed motors at all? Brushless motors exist, and unless they're trying to say "we've revolutionised the brushed motor and now it doesn't have brushes" (i.e., claiming theyve "invented" the brushless motor) it doesn't really make sense that they would mention brushed motors at all; unless their motor is significantly different to a standard brushless motor - hence, my question..

Comment: That is not clear in your question - much like the dyson marketing blurb...

Comment: Haha, fair enough. Do you have any insight now it has been clarified?

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is just a [Brushless DC Electric motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor)

What Dyson seems best at is marketing their tech and branding it to sound exciting.

Comment: So does that mean that the coils are on the stator and not the rotor, and it just looks that way in the pictures?

Comment: You can make a brushless motor either way.

Comment: @Drew Is that true though? From the wiki article linked in this answer: "In all brushless motors, the coils are stationary." Which means that the coils will always be on the stator of a brushless motor doesn't it? You could configure it so that the stator is either in the centre or the outside of the motor, but the coils are always stationary. It appears in this Dyson motor that the coils are on the rotor, but it doesn't have brushes - so does that mean it is still a "brushless motor", and if so, does that mean the wiki article is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, yes I believe you're correct, I was thinking of inrunners and outrunners. Technically the coils do move in an induction motor, and it *is* brushess, but I wouldn't normally call that a "brushless motor".